# Parsing and converting a typescript object yields undesired result

Tags: typescript

I got an object which looks like this:

```
{\"key1\":{\"cluster_region\":\"centralus\"},\"key2\":{\"cluster_region\":\"westeurope\"}}
```

I'm trying to make a list of objects from that given object. Each object in the list should have a 2 fields called "index" and "region". The "index" value is the keys' values from the original object ("key1" and "key2") and the region value is the corresponding "cluster_region" from the original object.

I tried doing it like this:

```
const allrecords: Record<string, { cluster_region: string }> = initialObject;
console.log("all records: " + JSON.stringify(allrecords));
const allList = Object.entries(allrecords).map(([key, value]) => ({
        index: key,
        region: value.cluster_region
      }));
```

I do see the correct value of `allrecords` in the `console.log` which is the initial object. However, the list itself I'm getting looks like this:

```
[{"index":"0"},{"index":"1"},{"index":"2"} ... ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example of what you are doing runs properly and produces the expected output in the typescript playground, as visible [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2B5ARgKwKbCwC8MAUgMoYByAdAA4oBOEeAFAEQDeAOuwNZ4AngEZeALh7tgaAK7Q8jAPqM8AczjhxvYHjBRG6ObwC+AGl4DBAJnGTpcqAuVqNYLewDueeTMYg6eCbG7ACUAFCgkLDoaCqgjAAmEGIwAEoEIIkAPNCMCKqmMJww9vJKKurgKbn5MMYAfDAkCEiomLgEUADcYRHgECBoeDRoIKocMTBxmUkp7DAA1GSUtDVg6gBmgqwx04kQISE9fVEwMQAycNBNMNj4hDS6+nDeO2ixGfshNAC2KHSsVgAbUshQAboY8ABdEJNRqsThhGDIlHIhAJPAADxSoKRqJRFVcKQhsmGpUc5Rc4DxqOMh2OkQGQxGYzeaEu0COQA)

This suggests that either:

- Your data is malformed
- You are modifying the string form of the input, who’s `Object.entries` `key` would be the indices `0..length`
- The code that you are running doesn't match the code that you posted.

I would assume in this case that the code you are running doesn't match, because you are seeing `[{"index":"0"},{"index":"1"},{"index":"2"} ... ]` which suggests that `index` is being assigned the actual index value of the data.

Please check the code that you are running locally and verify that it, and the data that you are receiving match what you are stating, and then update your question accordingly.

Comment: You are correct. I was accidentally working on the string of the object instead of the object itself so I had to add JSON.parse(initialObject). If you could add this as a reason in your "This suggests that either...", I will accept the answer

Comment: Edit has been added

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, please recheck the output. Also, you can parse your object in following way too.
[image: See output]